# problem to set permission with mkdir in php

Tags: php, mkdir

I know my question is similar to old ones answered many times. But stil, I don't understand why the following behavior. I'm on centos 7.9 with php 5.4.16.
Being the user, I can execute mkdir('/tmp/mydir', 0775) correctly

`drwxrwxr-x 3 john john      60 20 déc.  09:30 mydir`

When excuting as apache with `sudo -u apache` the php script either on CLI or with as an http request, I end up with

`drwxr-xr-x 3 apache  apache       60 20 déc.  09:22 mydir`

And a `sudo -u apache` with `chmod('./depth1',0775);` works. The behaviour is similar when I do this is a directory that I own where apache has write mode or even in a directory belonging to apache. The fact that I belong to apache group, and apache belongs to my group does'nt change either when making the test in a directory I own and where group has write rights.

Comment: The permissions are modified by the user's `umask`.

Comment: Thank you. Tha answer was as simple as this. And I did'nt see the note on this in the php.net page, sorry.